# Google Spreadsheet- Notify by email when someone edits a cell in a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

If someone edits the first row, an e-mail should be sent to A. If someone edits the second row,  an e-mail should be sent to B and so on.

```
if (edited cell was in range - first row) {
   //do something } 
if (edited cell was in range- second row) {
   //do something }
```

and so on.

Have already tried scripts available in Stack overflow, all are based on active cell. What if someone drags a value in a range of rows. The script would send an e-mail to the first active row cell only.

Found this, but fails when values are dragged over cells and I need over a range of each row.

```
function emailNotification() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
var recipient = "me@gmail.com";
var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "roster update");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script has simple triggers for edit events.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
From the onEdit docs:

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

You will notice when this trigger is fired it passes onEdit an object that contains a lot of info on this edit. You can view the object at:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

This object contains the Range object of the edit. The range object docs are at:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

From the range you can get which cells were edited with the getA1Notation() method and the values using the getValues() method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went through the document and all the parameters and tested with best to my knowledge. But it did not work out. I want  something like this:  `if (edited cell === first row) { //do something } if (edited cell === second row) { //do something } `and so on.

Comment: What is the parameter to identify a row?

Comment: Look at the getRow() method. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow(). So e.range.getRow() would give you the starting row of the range.